# Using information provided by html inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use information from a text input for running a script with it. How can I take the information from a text input in html?

Comment: There are a ton of ways. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value

Answer (score 1):

this example help you :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="txt" value="this is text">
        <button id="btn" onclick="fun()" >Click me</button>
        <script>
            function fun() {
                var mytext= document.getElementById("txt").value;
                alert(mytext);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```